# MS Teams - copy posts from one channel to another channel

Tags: microsoft-teams

In ms teams, if I can copy Posts from one Channel to another Channel?

If its please share the details or video links

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with programming. Surely, you could just try...

Comment: okay thanks, I find some solutions !!  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/education_ms/forum/all/teams-copy-content-from-one-channel-to-another/daed64c6-9a86-450b-87b3-5286c2397128

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pandi Mohan, you can not copy paste the post from one channel post to another. You can copy the link of the post and post it in other channel. Copy link option is available at top right menu of the post.